# C# Bitwise With Integers

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I am trying to preform a simple bitwise statement to see if a user has security. It seems to be ok until i introduce variables.

This Works:
    byte test = 1 & 3.

Won't work:
    byte a = 1;
    byte b = 3;
    byte test = a & b;

Is there anyway that I can get this to work?

Comment: Define "won't work". What is your specific problem?

Comment: The error I get is:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: That error actually tells you 1) what's wrong, and 2) what to do about it.

Comment: I've never had to cast something in C# i'm still learning. But next time i'll know what to do :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast it back to a `byte` as a bitwise AND will return an `int`, so do this:

```
byte a = 1;
byte b = 3;
byte test = (byte)(a & b);
```